# Допускается ли одновременно атрибут charset и name в элементе meta?

Tags: html5, utf-8, атрибуты, meta

В спецификации html5 в описании элемента meta говорится следующее:

> Exactly one of the name, http-equiv, and charset, attributes must be
>   specified.

Примерный перевод: Только один из атрибутов может быть использован: name, http-equiv, или charset.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что не могу писать так?

```
<meta name="author" content="Sergey" charset="utf-8">
```

Т.е. либо я пишу в одном html документе

```
<meta name="author" content="Sergey">
```

либо

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Допустим если я хочу указать автора Sergey т.е. типа так

```
<meta name="author" content="Sergey">
```

то как мне, чтобы соблюсти стандарт html5 указать еще и кодировку utf-8, ведь по стандарту нельзя одновременно использовать meta name и utf-8? Или может я неправильно перевел стандарт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что не могу писать так?
>
> ```
> <meta name="author" content="Sergey" charset="utf-8">
> ```

Правильно. Так как элемент `meta` позволяет задать **только одну** из трёх характеристик (name, charset, http-equiv) документа **за раз**.

В данном же случае нужно написать так:

```
<meta name="author" content="Sergey">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Так как количество элементов meta не ограничивается одним его экземпляром, за исключением `<meta charset="что-то там">`, поскольку она должна задаваться один раз.